# Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again

Tags: reactjs, invisible-recaptcha

I am using react-google-invisible-recaptcha. but it is not working when the page load it shows an alert like "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again" even though the internet is faster. how can I use invisible-reCAPTCHA. is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem by giving valid domain address while registering recaptcha.

Answer (score 6):

While registering reCaptcha, I gave `Domain` as `localhost`. It solved the error for me.
(I am using Visual Studio 2017, and I am running my web application on localhost.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (continuous messages "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again") which drove me crazy.
Then I discovered that I had registered a "reCaptcha V2" for my site, but used the *site key* and the *secret key* to create an "invisible reCaptcha".
After registering an "invisible reCaptcha" for the same domain, I got a different key pair that worked flawlessly.
I concluded that the three types of reCaptcha (V2, invisible and Android) produce specific key pairs. Every key pair is unique for the reCaptcha type that has been registered for the domain, and cannot be used interchangeably for other reCaptcha types. On the other hand, one may register different reCaptcha types for the same domain, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Define domain name like this, While working with localhost**

[image]

Comment: Is it an answer to the question?

Comment: yes, Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.        because, difficult to understand how to define localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue of "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again".

I used the site key and secret key for different domains and I delete all but remain only one. Reenter the key and seems working now.

Edit: It is still not working, so i tried to use v3 instead of v2 and seems less problem (haven't seen any yet)